# Azure Kubernetes(AKS) External IP not reachable

Tags: azure-aks, nginx-ingress, azure-public-ip

The external IP which is listed in my nginx loadbalancer service is not reachable(ping/telnet/curl)

```
kc get services | grep nginx
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.11.13     20.166.xx.xx   80:32282/TCP,443:31592/TCP                                                          32m
```

I've tried reinstalling ingress-nginx, and installed the latest version, but no luck.

Nginx pod logs also don't return any errors.

I think that it's not a problem with my ingress but a problem with the external ip(azure)

I recently did an upgrade of kubernetes, it's at 1.25.2 now, I assume that the new k8s version has some bugs, but i've not been able to identify any.

I've gone trough https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/connection-issues-application-hosted-aks-cluster
And did all the steps, everything is fine.

I couldn't make an azure support ticket because it's not free for "technical" issues, and I can't afford to pay for support. I've sent a mail to support@microsoftsupport.com , but no replies yet and I think they might just ignore me because they expect official support requests. So if anyone knows a mail on which they'll reply please share withn me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I had another LB service for some proxy, and it's external IP was accessible, so I checked the difference between the services and noticed that in the nginx service the ports were defined like http instead of 80:

```
This doesn't work
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32282/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.2.37:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31592/TCP

This works
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32282/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.2.37:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31592/TCP
```

Comment: Tried this, it was absolutely not the root cause of the problem. After solving the issue (problem in my case was I was using the "basic" instead of "standard" SKU for the load-balancer and public IP), I reverted to the "This doesn't work"-snippet, which works perfectly fine for me.